# Jekyll: only show recent posts excluding some catogaries

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am new to Jekyll. I know that Jekyll supports to show recent post with the following code:

```
<div id="recent-posts" class="recent-posts">
  {% for this_post in paginator.posts %}
  <div class="post">
      <a href="{{ this_post.url }}">
        <h2 class="post-title">{{ this_post.title }}</h2>
      </a>
      {% include category_info %}
      {% include source_info %}
  </div>
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

But I would like not to show a category of posts, saying the category name is `"notshowing"`. How can I make it?

Answer (score 4):

To avoid showing a specific category you can use the `unless` filter:

> executes a block of code only if a certain condition is not met (that
>   is, if the result is false).

So for example, inside the `for` loop, use `{% unless post.categories contains "notshowing"%}`

In your example, using the site posts `site.posts` instead of `paginator.posts` (you can adjust that to fit what you need) it would look like:

```
<div id="recent-posts" class="recent-posts">
  {% for post in site.posts %}
  {% unless post.categories contains "notshowing"%}
  <div class="post">
      <a href="{{ post.url }}">
        <h2 class="post-title">{{ post.title }}</h2>
      </a>
  </div>
  {% endunless %}
  {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: this did the job nicely.